# Google Analytics report for the advertising cost of an event label

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, analytics-events, cost

I have a problem with Google Analytics report that I'm trying to do.

I've set up some signups on my forms as Events. These are recorded correctly in the Behaviour reports, that show event actions and labels etc.

However, when I come to do a custom report, it doesn't seem possible to select both the "Event Label" in the dimension section and the "Advertising -> Cost" in the metric section at the same time.

I'm wondering why it isn't possible to understand how much cost each Event Label incurred?

It seems very strange that it's not possible to mix these things. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're requesting a column that doesn't relate to the event data. Cost is only tracked against advertisements (as the category suggests). You need to describe a method that allows Analytics to link the two.

If you want to track the 'cost' of an event, try setting it as a goal. You can then look at it from the other direction - pull up campaigns and see how many events were triggered per campaign.

Answer (score 1):

One way of getting the data that you are looking for is to create an [advanced segment](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3124493?hl=en) for users that have the event.   When that advanced segment is applied, the reports will only show data for users with that event.

You can then view a report that shows advertising cost and see how it is related to that event.

Comment: I wish I could accept 2 answers, because this one is so good.